# Assign value 0xB33C to register $t0

Tags: assembly, mips

Assign value 0xB33C to register $t0.

The answer to this is: `ori $t0, $zero, 0xB33C` but, I'm confused why. I thought the answer would be `addi $t0, $t0, 0xB33C`.

Can someone explain this to me please? I'm not sure how the `ori` instruction works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the answer would be `addi $t0, $t0, 0xB33C`

Perhaps you mean `addi $t0, $zero, 0xB33C`? Anyway, the problem with `addi` in this case is that it sign-extends the 16-bit immediate value encoded in the instruction word. So you'd end up with `0xFFFFB33C`.

`ori` does a bitwise OR, which means that each bit in the result will be set if the corresponding bit is set in any of the inputs. The truth table for that is:

```
 IN    OUT
----------
0 0  ->  0
0 1  ->  1
1 0  ->  1
1 1  ->  1
```

As you might be able to see, performing a bitwise OR between zero and some value X, will give you X as the result. So `ori $t0,$zero,0xB33C` gives you `$t0 = 0 bitwise OR 0xB33C`, i.e. `$t0 = 0xB33C`.